# Is MS SCSF-CAB framework outdated, is there a better framework now?

Tags: scsf

Seems no more discussion about MS SCSF-CAB, is this framework outdated? is there a better framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSFT is promoting WPF now, the SCSF counterpart of that is PRISM

http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF

Comment: thanks, but I mostly use Winform, will this works on winform?

Answer (score 1):

In My project  I found the SCSF is not outdate for Winform Programming.PRISM is just a SCSF's another specifical implement in WPF using some features of WPF.Maybe SCSF is hard for SoftwareDeveloper beginner, it's used in some complex projects.I found Petrel's architecture is more like SCSF.(Petrel is platform software developed by  [Schlumberger](http://www.slb.com/))

and there is a [SCSF2010 addin for vs2012 and vs2013](https://scsf2012.codeplex.com/releases/view/106830)

Comment: thanks man, can i add you as friends to discuss some question, since we are all from china